# OWL Center image size and spacing

Tags: owl-carousel

I would like to have slider with center image larger than side images.
So far I was able to it like so: [OWL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm80A.jpg)
But now there is spaces between images. How to remove these spaces without cropping center image.

What I am missing here?

CSS:

```
.gallery_list .owl-carousel {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.gallery_list .owl-carousel .item {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery_list .owl-carousel .active:not(.center) {
    transform: scale(0.8); /* Adjust the scale for the center image */
}
```

JS:

```
$owl_home.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin:5,
    nav:true,
    dots: false,
    center: true,
    autoplay:false,
    mouseDrag: true,
    navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:false,
            mouseDrag: true,
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
```